# Is it possible to create SMILES representation out of DNA/RNA-Oligonucleotides (~50 nts)?

Tags: rna

I want to use physico chemical descriptors of single stranded DNA/RNA-Oligonucleotides in order to model certain properties. To generate these descriptors i need a computer understandable representation of these oligonucleotides, e.g. the SMILES representation. So far i could not find of any method to generate these SMILES representations out of the primary structure of these oligonucleotides.
I am wondering if someone knows of a software, that takes the primary sequence of a single stranded DNA-Oligonucleotide with e.g. 50 nts as input and gives the SMILES representation as output.
So far i could find nothing that would accomplish this task, although, at least to me, it seems like a straight forward task.

I will appreciate every constructive thought on that.

Thanks!

**EDIT:** Add some form of input and output file

As requested here an example of input and output pair:

input should be primary sequence:
TCA

output should be the corresponding SMILES string:
O=C(C(C)=CN1[C@@]2([H])C([H])([H])C@@([H])C@([H])O2)NC1=O

This example was generated with chemdraw 20.1.1.

For my use case i need a software, that convert many (like 50k - 1000k) primary sequences of single stranded DNA/RNA with a length of about 50 nts into the corresponding SMILES string. Ideally would be some sort of python package but anything else would help also a lot!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Can you please provide an example input file and example output file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like various chemical software toolkits can export SMILES, for example [OpenBabel](http://openbabel.org/wiki/SMILES), using the [babel command line tool.](http://openbabel.org/wiki/Babel) I am not readily seeing the best way to read e.g. a FASTA, though. Another option would be [ChemDraw](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwi52YLa98r9AhVPMTQIHT8QCRkQFnoECAwQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fperkinelmerinformatics.com%2Fproducts%2Fresearch%2Fchemdraw&usg=AOvVaw0BmVb9fWH4mKXs22TzVe39).

[This researchgate thread](https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_do_I_convert_my_peptides_into_SMILES_strings) has a lot of information on peptide->SMILES conversion, I don't see nucleotides though.

One option, though it would be a little finicky, would be to look up the nucleotides SMILES strings on [PubChem](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/#query=adenosine) and then write a script to string them together (with a monophosphate) based on an input sequence. It seems like [there is some related tooling already in rdkit](https://github.com/rdkit/rdkit/issues/3080), but a convenient API doesn't seem to exist yet. [The developer does have one suggestion for peptides](https://Born,%20Jannis.%20(2020).%20Re:%20How%20do%20I%20convert%20my%20peptides%20into%20SMILES%20strings?.%20Retrieved%20from:%20https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_do_I_convert_my_peptides_into_SMILES_strings/5eaff1007b75ea5bbf031b32/citation/download.), which would translate into something like this for nucleotides:

```
from rdkit import Chem

nt_mol = Chem.MolFromFASTA("ACATATAT", flavor=9)  # flavor param notes as DNA
Chem.MolToSMILES(nt_mol)
```

To do this across many nucleotides you could hook it up to biopython to iterate across a FASTA file.

The nucleotide `flavor` option exists, but there is a note that only peptide is supported. I don't know whether that means the feature is experimental or is not implemented.